# Replace string letters with nth alphabet character in PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

How can I replace the letters in a string with their +n corespondent from the alphabet?

For instance, replace each character with its +4 corespondent, as below:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c d
```

So, if I have the string `johnny`, it should become `nslrrc`.

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: 13 is simple [rot13()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php). <hint see the user notes

Comment: if this is being used for anything you would consider 'secure', in any way at all, you need to reconsider.

Comment: @Spudley It’s not, I’m just trying to mess with some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a character-for-character replacement with [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$shiftBy = 4;
$alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

$newAlpha = substr($alphabet, $shiftBy) . substr($alphabet, 0, $shiftBy);

echo strtr("johnny", $alphabet, $newAlpha);

// nslrrc
```

Of course, this assumes all lowercase as in your example. Capitals complicate things.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/qNLli2

*Bonus: also works with negative shifts*

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$length=strlen($str);
$ret = "";
$n=5;
$n=$n-1;
    for($i = 0, $l = strlen($str); $i < $l; ++$i) 
    {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if (97 <= $c && $c < 123) {
            $ret.= chr(($c + $n + 7) % 26 + 97);
        } else if(65 <= $c && $c < 91) {
            $ret.= chr(($c + $n + 13) % 26 + 65);
        } else {
            $ret.= $str[$i];
        }
    }
    echo $ret;
?>
```

[DEMO 1 (Eg: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)](http://ideone.com/rUEc65)

[DEMO 2 (Eg: johhny)](http://ideone.com/RXOk4R)

Answer (score 1):

This is a way:

```
<?php

$newStr = "";
$str = "johnny";

define('DIFF', 4);
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {        
    $newStr .= chr((ord($str[$i])-97+DIFF)%26+97);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make an array of letters. For each letter in array[$key] value, echo array[$key+4]. If the $key+4 is bigger than the size of array, do some basic calculations and forward it to start.